# Scanning with nmap from LAN or WAN, any difference?

Tags: unix, networking, nmap

Does it make any difference if I use nmap from LAN or WAN?
For example, I have router and scan it from LAN, will results of scan same if I will scan from WAN ( Wide Area Network)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of scanning a device from a system on the LAN side of the device won't necessarily be the same as the results of scanning it from the WAN side. If you are checking for open ports, a device, such as a router, may allow connectivity to a port from the LAN side, but not from the WAN side. E.g., HTTP access to administer a device or [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) queries may be allowed from the LAN side, but not the WAN side.